# Getting token from redirect url

Tags: c#, winforms, api, authentication, token

I am developing a Windows Form Application in C# and have discovered that I am able to link the user's account with their UK government account through the use of their web services. I have got set up with them and they have advised that I direct the user to a browser where they will log into their government account (using my unique URL). They will then redirect the browser to a localhost URL which will contain the token needed for me to make any calls to their web service.

How do I go about implementing this and how do I get the token from the localhost URL?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into using a different OAuth flow if the service provider supports it.

Comment: What have you tried? Usually government level APIs are very well documented with examples. Try opening a web browser control in your app at _your unique url_ and inspect the url when the page next navigates.

Comment: `They will redirect the browser to a localhost URL which will contain the token` that means you need to have a web application with an endpoint where they will redirect... In the web application code you need to get the query string parameter get the token sent by them.

Comment: Ok, I have a Chromium browser control within my application and whenever the user needs to sync their government account, the browser will open allowing them to enter their credentials. However, the browser won't redirect to the specified URL and I am then unable to get the token

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I have inspected the redirect URL in both chrome and within my cefsharp control. Chrome shows the url without the token (I suspect for security reasons) and the browser control cant open the url as its localhost

Comment: Do you have access to the body or headers of the failed request? You should be able to intercept the _LoadingStateChanged_ event to scrape the token and close the browser. implementing an IRequestHandler might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38702320/1690217